# Error when scanning project with Mend Advise

Tags: spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I installed the Mend Advise plugin for Spring Tools. When I scan my project, I am getting the following error for all my projects:

```
An internal error occured during: "Collect Dependencies for test-project".
'org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectFacade[]
org.eclipose.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectRegistry.getProjects()'
```

I have tried restarting and switching workspaces with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.